# How to solve:" Cannot read property 'classList' of null "?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm sitting here starting to create my first [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) app.

During this, I'm trying to add a certain styling to an < a > tag, by adding the class "TEST" with Javescript "onclick".

However this is returning the error: "Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

Now, I get that this is because the GetElementById is somehow returning null or undefined, but I cannot figure out why!

I've followed the guide from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) and it is late right now, but I'm pretty sure I've done exactly as they have. I've also read the related posts, but nothing have helped me out so far.

**My Code:**

```js
window.onload = function () {console.log('JS loaded!')};

function addClassStyle () {
    var x = document.getElementById('test')
    x.classList.add('TEST')
};
```

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
}

li {
    color: #ebebeb;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    height: 100%;
    width: 95px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.36);
}

.TEST {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Getting Stuff Done</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- <h1>Hello World!</h1>
We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>. -->

<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Inbox</li></a>
        <a href="projekter.html" id="test" onclick="addClassStyle()"><li>Projekter</li></a>
        <a href="forecast.html"><li>Forecast</li></a>
        <a href="review.html"><li>Review</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: x is null- there was no such element found for the “test” ID. Did you mean to CREATE an element instead?

Comment: Once you fix the onclick so that it doesn't redirect to the nonexistent `projekter.html`, the error you describe does not seem to appear... (can you change the snippet so that it illustrates the error, or describe how to replicate it?)

Comment: Try adding `event` to `onclick="addClassStyle(event)"` and also add it on the function itself as an argument. Then instead of getting the element with `document.getElementById()` just do `event.currentTarget.classList.add('TEST');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with you CSS -> `ul a.test li` 
Also your click was loading another page so would not work. added `event.preventDefault()`

```js
window.onload = function () {console.log('JS loaded!')};

function addClassStyle () {
    event.preventDefault();
    let x = document.getElementById('test');
    console.log(x);
    x.classList.add('test');
    x.classList.forEach(c => console.log(c));
};
```

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
}

li {
    color: #ebebeb;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    height: 100%;
    width: 95px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.36);
}

ul a.test li {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Inbox</li></a>
        <a href="projekter.html" id="test" onclick="addClassStyle()"><li>Projekter</li></a>
        <a href="forecast.html"><li>Forecast</li></a>
        <a href="review.html"><li>Review</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright I see what you're saying about the CSS. I'm not 100% sure I understand why the "onclick" is not working however. Can you maybe explain why it wouldn't work as it is loading another page?

Comment: I figured it out! Well quite simple what you're saying now that I get it really.. But thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Awesome I am glad your back on track. Happy coding !!

Comment: Thanks! And you too!